# App crashes when clicking a Button

Tags: android, exception, button

Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.jannes.app, PID: 16569
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method buttona1(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button2'
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10814)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

This is the error I get when running the app, I made multiple buttons and there not working (buttons linking to a internet site and buttons to another activity in the app). Hopefully anyone can help me. I am totally new to programming so please use childish language.

layout

```
<Button
    android:text="Magister"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="buttona1"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Java file

```
public class FourthFragment extends Fragment{


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fourth_layout, container, false);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused") // it's actually used, just injected by Butter Knife
public void buttona1(View view){
    Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.nl"));
    getActivity().startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code too in the question.

Comment: @Jannes van den Bogert, Perhaps you are referencing buttona1() method with a wrong button id

Comment: see your xml you would have defined for an Button.

Comment: **never** declare click listeners in the XML. You are getting this errors because you declared listener in XML. You for sure will burn in hell if you declare listeners in XML

Comment: @VladMatvienko How can I fix this?

Comment: are sure your button is in fourth_layout ??

Comment: @PushpendraChoudhary I am

Comment: remove onclick declaration from xml, and use it from java `setOnClickListener()`

Comment: @VladMatvienko So I add setOnClickListener(button2) in the Fourthfragment and where should I? sorry Im starter

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like this in your onCreate.

```
    button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        //your code
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `onCreateView` method with this,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fourth_layout, container, false);
    final Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.nl"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

And remove the `android:onClick` attribute from the xml.
You don't need `buttona1` method if you follow this.

Answer (score 0):

> @SuppressWarnings("unused") // it's actually used, just injected by Butter Knife
>
> Butter Knife

For ButterKnife, you can simply use following

```
@OnClick(R.id.button2)
public void onClick(){
    
}
```

Also remove this

```
android:onClick="buttona1"
```

and don't forget about

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
}
```